# How to create a function that is dependent on an array of values?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, matplotlib

The function that I want to code is f(x) = beta/(pi*(x^(2) + beta^(2))
for beta values 0, 10, 20, 50, 100

So i want to integrate this function over the range of x from negative infinity to infinity. I have the basis of the code below but am unsure how to pass an array through for beta.

Thanks for the help!

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from sympy import Symbol 
from math import pi
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def integrand(x):
    return limit(beta/(np.pi*(x**2 + beta**2)));
xlo = '-inf'
xhi = 'inf'
result = quad(integrand, xlo, xhi, args=(beta))
print result
```

Comment: `import scipy as quad`?  Don't you mean `from scipy.integrate import quad`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from math import pi
import numpy as np

def integrand(x, beta):
    return beta/(np.pi*(x**2 + beta**2))

for beta in [0., 1., 10., 20., 50., 100.]:
    xlo = -np.inf
    xhi = np.inf
    result = quad(integrand, xlo, xhi, args=(beta))
    print('beta: {}, result: {}, error estimate: {}'.format(beta, *result))
```

The integral should always be 1 if beta > 0 for this expression, regardless of beta, if you [integrate it](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%20-inf%20to%20inf%20of%20beta%2F(pi%20*%20(x%5E2%20%2B%20beta%5E2))%20with%20respect%20to%20x). I wasn't sure why `limit` was in there or where it was supposed to come from, so I removed it. If beta is zero then the function is undefined at x=0, and you might want to be careful about that.